# What happens when you concatenate dataframes that can be fit in memory with pandas?

Tags: pandas

My question is: when you concatenate dataframes that can be stored in memory, eventually will you end up with a dataframe that can't be fit in memory? Or pandas does this whenever you call any method on the dataframe?

Comment: Are you asking if `pd.concat` copies or just adds a reference?  Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean, since obviously an arbitrarily large object will eventually not fit in memory.

Comment: @user3483203 yeah, basically that.

Comment: With `concat's` default behavior, yes the frames will be copied, but you can change that behavior which won't copy frames if it can avoid it.

Comment: @user3483203 and that would only be by setting the parameters ``copy = False''?

Comment: Yes.  When you read the documentation for `concat` which part was confusing about the `copy`? That might help me explain better.

Comment: @user3483203 well, basically what I want to do is to concatenate "n" dataframes and just accessing the one that contains certain index number. I don't know if this is possible.